# Login To Facebook Python

Tags: python, facebook

I am trying to log in to facebook using python but i am unable to login. I have posted earlier but no one gave me any satisfactory solution.
I have used Requests and Selenium but both did not work. selenium always open facebook in arabic means it is opening different session and temporary chrome profile that is why it is not allowing me to login, so i tried to load the default profile and then tried to login again, this time it loaded the default profile but in arabic, and again i cant login, it says that email is not correct. I am able to login in using same email and password manually. The error comes only when i try to login using Requests or Selenium.
Actually am trying to scrape some data from facebook. Please give me some solution why this is happening to me.
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Facebook doesn't allow you to scrape them. You have to use the API.

Comment: then how the libraries like  this https://pypi.org/project/facebook-scraper/  doing that?

Comment: They scrape. That doesn't mean Facebook is ok with it.

Comment: I know but how they do, i have tried but facebook does not even allow me to login via automation why?

Comment: You would have to ask them.

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver
# https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
facebook = "https://facebook.com/login"
browser.get(facebook)

email = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="email"]')
password = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="pass"]')
email.send_keys("EMAIL")
password.send_keys("PASSWORD")

login = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="loginbutton"]')
login.click()
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes

Comment: hi @odd i have used this approach but didn't work for me, as i said that selenium opens new session that does not allow me to login. any ways thanks to at least answer